# Capistrano - Authentication Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app using Capistrano but when I run `cap deploy:setup` I get

> connection failed for: 123.456.789.0:12345 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deployer@123.456.789.0)

without been asked to input a password.

However if I run `ssh -p 12345 deployer@123.456.789.0` everything works as expected.

On SO many suggest not to use net-ssh 2.8.0

In my Gemfile I have

`gem 'capistrano', '2.15.5'
gem "net-ssh", '2.8.1', :git => "https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh"`

The deploy config file is pretty standard and it includes

`default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true`

Am I missing anything here? What could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the contents of Gemfile.lock and results of `gem list net-ssh` to ensure that 2.8.0 isn't still hanging around in there somewhere?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can remove this address from your ~/.ssh/known_hosts and try again. Also, are you sure you created the user "deployer" from your root session ?

Answer (score 0):

If you got access you could just add your SSH public key into the deployers ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

I think that is the preferred way of doing it nowadays, also frees you from having to type the password out every deploy!

Hope that helps!